# Surrealdb Rust SDK select function not working as in Documentation

Tags: rust, surrealdb

While using the Rust SDK for Surrealdb, where i don't know what i do different compared to the official documentation. Selecting all records from a table works fine, however selecting a specified record doesn't give me a result.

**Working Example selecting all records in the table**

here `self.db` is a `Surreal<Client>`:

```
pub async fn get_all_sensors(&self) -> Result<Vec<Sensor>, SDBError>{
    let response_data: Result<Vec<Sensor>, surrealdb::Error> = self.db.select("sensor").await;
    match response_data {
        Ok(response_data) => Ok(response_data),
        Err(_) => Err(SDBError)
        }
}
```

which will give me the following result:

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "foo"
    }
]
```

however trying to select only the "foo" entry like the following:

```
pub async fn get_sensor(&self, sensor: Sensor) -> Option<Sensor>{
    let response: Result<Option<Sensor>, surrealdb::Error> = self.db.select(("sensor", "foo")).await;
     match response {
         Ok(output) => output,
         Err(_) => None,
}
```

in Surrealist i can see that the entry also has the right "id".

```
{
    "id": "sensor:foo",
    "uuid": "foo"
}
```

Implementation is very similar to the Documentation: [Surrealdb Rust SDK](https://surrealdb.com/docs/integration/sdks/rust)
Only difference is that i don't use the `await?` but `await`then matching the Result manually.

Also tried out the version (for testing) with `self.db.select("sensor", "foo").range((Bound::Included(""), Bound::Exluded("foo")).await.unwrap()` as they have done it in their tests [Surrealdb Github Test](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/blob/main/lib/src/api/method/tests/mod.rs) on Line 131.

One difference that I can see is that they use a `Lazy<Surreal<Client>>` but I don't see that as the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your example as closely as possible but I can't get the same result. I first created the record using

```sql
CREATE sensor:foo SET uuid = "foo";
```

and then ran the following code

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use surrealdb::engine::remote::ws::{Client, Ws};
use surrealdb::opt::auth::Root;
use surrealdb::opt::RecordId;
use surrealdb::Surreal;

struct Db {
        db: Surreal<Client>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Sensor {
        id: RecordId,
        uuid: String,
}

impl Db {
        async fn get_sensor(&self) -> Option<Sensor> {
                let response: Result<Option<Sensor>, surrealdb::Error> =
                        self.db.select(("sensor", "foo")).await;
                match response {
                        Ok(output) => output,
                        Err(_) => None,
                }
        }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> surrealdb::Result<()> {
        let db = Surreal::new::<Ws>("localhost:8000").await?;

        db.signin(Root {
                username: "root",
                password: "root",
        })
        .await?;

        db.use_ns("test").use_db("test").await?;

        let db = Db {
                db,
        };

        let sensor = db.get_sensor().await;

        println!("{sensor:?}");

        Ok(())
}
```

This prints

```rust
Some(Sensor { id: Thing { tb: "sensor", id: String("foo") }, uuid: "foo" })
```

In my case both the `surrealdb` crate and server are on `v1.0.0`. Which versions are you using for both?

> Also tried out the version (for testing) with `self.db.select("sensor", "foo").range((Bound::Included(""), Bound::Exluded("foo")).await.unwrap()`

`self.db.select("sensor", "foo")` shouldn't compile. That method only takes one argument.

`.range((Bound::Included(""), Bound::Exluded("foo"))` tells the database to return all records whose `id` starts from `""` up to but not including `"foo"`, sorted by `id`. This can be written simply as `.range("".."foo")`. As you may expect, this method only works with queries that return multiple results. If you try to use it with something that fetches a specific record like `db.select(("sensor", "foo"))` you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes i wrote the other version for testing different as i implemented it (as you corrected me right). Also i tried your code which worked perfectly fine so i knew where to look now. Finally it was a stupid mistake by my side that i forgot to register the service since i called the method on an actix web route. Anyways, thanks for taking your time to help out!!